# Undefined reference error in linking

Tags: c, gcc, linker, cygwin

When I'm trying to link two programs with extension `.o` , `gcc` compiler "throws" me that `undefined reference` and something else that I don't understand.

I link these programs at `Cygwin` terminal with that command :

```
gcc -o file file1.o file2.o
```

I don't have any other library to include such as `math.h` (so `-lm` needed).

I just have two functions in a header file and I include that to my main program.

And I get this :

```
file1.o:file1.c(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `Function1'
file1.o:file1.c:(.text+0x104): undefined reference to `Function2'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: file1.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.eh_frame'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: It'll be hard to diagnose your problem without seeing the code. Can you please post the relevant code?

Comment: its little long but i will try... :

Comment: Are they referencing each other?  Sometimes you need to add the .o files into a link path more than once.

Comment: Yes , they are referencing each other, but what do you mean to write?

Comment: what happens if you try `gcc -o file file1.c file2.c`?

Comment: I've tried it already , the same happens.

Comment: gcc -o file file1.o file2.o file1.o file2.o

Comment: no such file or directory...^

Comment: Where is your main located?

Comment: At file1.c . At file2 I have the functions I need , and a header file that I have included in both of .c files .

Comment: gcc -o file file1.c file2.o file2.o   You may have to break the main into a separate file.

Comment: @Jim that causes more errors.

Comment: Why do you have a single header for both files?  You should probably have a separate header file for each file.

Comment: You are right I just made three header files , that and included them in both of .c files. Then these header include each other when needed...But i get the same error again.

Comment: Are your functions `Function1` and `Function2` defined as `extern` functions or not?

Answer (score 0):

For objects that reference each other, sometimes you need to include them in the path more than once so the linker can make all the correct connections.

```
gcc -o file file1.o file2.o file1.o file2.o
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors "`undefined reference`" errors you see are produced by the linker, which when trying to satisfy the external references for `file1.o` cannot find `Function1` or `Function2`.  Under the assumption that those symbols are in `file2.o` a simple solution would be ensure `file2.o` gets linked first, so:

```
gcc -o file file2.o file1.o
```

Note, the order in which object files are presented for linking is important.  Of course, if `file2.o` requires symbols that are present in `file1.o` then we are back to the same problem of circular dependency.

If you can't eliminate the circular dependency, a "hack" that is often used is to include the object files more than once in the link command, e.g:

```
gcc -o file file1.o file2.o file1.o
```

This approach doesn't really scale to a large solution however.  What you ideally want is for the link to search through a "bag" of object files for the symbols needed.  This behaviour can be achieved by using an archive file that contains object files.  The GNU linker at least will search through the files in the archive to try to resolve the symbols.  Thus:

```
ar cr libfiles.a file1.o file2.o

gcc -o file libfiles.a file1.o file2.o
```